# PHP fetch with file_get_contents() funtion

Tags: php, json, preg-match, fetch, file-get-contents

i want to get m3u8 link from this site on other php page

for example : this is the site : "view-source:http://lideo.ru/embed/9528"

i want to extract only this m3u8 to other php page : http://hls.lideo.ru/liveapp/09528_bd608448e6c4a218d16b1f7b4018f6e8/index.m3u8?tokenhash=TIai4tLuWZHdLOS5mjNOqw

I'm tried this code but seems not working

```
$url = "http://lideo.ru/embed/9528";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match('@m3u8([^"]+)@',$contents,$rtmp);
$link = urldecode($link[0]);
echo $link;
```

Any help please because i'm not soo good in php :)

thanks

Comment: what you get in it

Comment: i get only a white page , i think my code is wrong because i'm not soo good in php , can you help me plz

Comment: The '@m3u8([^"]+)@' makes it seem like you're trying to read this as XML. You'll need to import the URL in a DOMdocument and use XPATH to get the value

Comment: variable name issue here. `$link[0]` must be `$rtmp[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://lideo.ru/embed/9528";
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

preg_match('/(https?\:\/\/[^\']*\.m3u8\?[^\']*)/', $contents, $result);
$link = urldecode($result[0]);
echo $link;
```